# Web service JAX-RS multiple threads: passing INFORMATION

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, jersey, stateless

I'm building a JAX-RS based web-service with these configurations:

- IDE: **Eclipse**
- Build: **Maven**
- Deployment:**Tomcat**
- Jax-RS annotations using **Jersey 1.8**
- DB : **mongoDB 3.0** with java driver (localhost)
- Client side: HTML pages with multiple forms processing both GET and POST methods

Actually, the program is developed around one main servlet in java with jax-rs annotations. That's the "entry point" for my app in order to handle the response/request from the server. The general goal is to achieve a web project containing several html pages, only with a JAX-RS controller.

I'm facing a requirement problem because of information that are POSTED by the user in a html form, but these inputs need to be retrieved in a @GET method from the same main servlet.
However, the app should not retrieve user's inputs with static parameters: it should be STATELESS (**requirement**) but still share information between multiple threads.

How can it be done, without using static content (variable **userParamList**), as shown below?? I was wondering if it was possible with a simple get/set for this field, but I know that Jax-RS threads are handled separately, so... :(

```
@Path("/rest")
public class BackendApp 
{

    private static String[] defaultParamList = {"timestamp","plcVersion","udmVersion","iotVersion","deviceName","manufacturer","model","sdk","primitiveName","result","status"};
    private static String[] userParamList = {};
    private static ArrayList<Document> container;
    private static java.nio.file.Path javaNIOPath;
    private static MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    private final MongoClient mongoClient;

    public BackendApp()
    {
         this(new MongoClient(connectionString));
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/postList") // FIRST pot that occurs at the beginning of this context (index.html at the root)
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Viewable getParamList(@FormParam("textarea") String textarea) throws IOException
    {
        userParamList = textarea.replaceAll("\\s*\\n\\s*","").split(","); //   REGEX expression filtering all the (multiple) blank spaces and carriage return
        return new Viewable("/query.html");
    } 

    @GET 
    @Path("/result")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response getHTML(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) throws IOException
    {
          MongoDatabase mongoDB = mongoClient.getDatabase("JSONRepository");
          MongoCollection<Document> coll = mongoDB.getCollection("TestColl");
          container = mongo.getParameters(userParamList, coll, queryParams);
          // userParamList is here static...

          // GET STUFF.....

    }
}
```

Thanks for all your answers.

PS: Static content works fine... so the problem is more focused on the problematic of *mulitple threads* with Jersey.

Comment: are you sure with this approach because what you want is something like web application and you trying to do this with web service, what you are trying with static will not work where there will be multiple request at same time

Comment: Indeed :) My requirements are to work only with Jax-Rs annotations. It will simplify the whole project and just processing the requests in one main method. What else are you thinking about?

Comment: OK. I solved this problem changing my way to do that. The parameters coming from an HTML page are now retrieved using jQuery. So the use of static content in my JAX-RS servlet is no more necessary.